# Subgroups of the multiplicative group of a Field

Tags: field-theory, cyclic-groups

I am reading S. Roman's book "Field Theory". In chapter $1$ I found the following exercise

*Let $F^*$ be the multiplicative group of all nonzero elements of a field $F$. We
have seen that if G is a finite subgroup of $F^*$, then G is cyclic. Prove that if
$F$ is an infinite field then no infinite subgroup  $G$ of $F^*$ is cyclic.*

I think that the question is wrong; for instance, if $F = \mathbb{Q}$, then the set $G = \{ 2^n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is an infinite cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}^*$

am I right or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Your example is correct; so the exercise, in the form you have typed here, is wrong. However it is better to  check if there are any assumptions before that exercise  that will exclude this.

Comment: That question is wrong in Roman's book. Wonder why he put it there.